# Weird heightmap borders

Tags: height-map

I want to make a Heightmap into a waterproof body. I create a plane - x times subdivide and then I put a Displace Modifier over it. If I select the texture I get weird edges. Unfortunately, I do not know the technical term for this and therefore have not found a solution. I would like to have the edges just below the lowest point of the terrain at the same height and close the surface. Can someone suggest a workflow to me?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

it might be because of the texture.
one quick solution is to make a uv on the object and make it a little bigger then the texture and after that set the Displace modifier to use you uv in texture coordinate options.

[image: uv editor view]